# ONNX with custom ops from TensorFlow in Java

Tags: java, tensorflow, onnx, onnxruntime, tf2onnx

in order to make use of Machine Learning in Java, I'm trying to train a model in TensorFlow, save it as ONNX file and then use the file for inference in Java. While this works fine with simple models, it's getting more complicated using pre-processing layers, as they seem to depend on custom operators.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification

As an example, this Colab deals with text classification and uses an TextVectorization layer this way:

```py
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
def custom_standardization2(input_data):
    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
    stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, '<br />',' ')
    return tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html, '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '')


vectorize_layer = layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization2,
    max_tokens=max_features,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length
)
```

It is used as pre-processing layer in the compiled model:

```py
export_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    vectorize_layer,
    model,
    layers.Activation('sigmoid')
])

export_model.compile(loss=losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False), optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

In order to create the ONNX file I save the model as protobuf and then convert it to ONNX:

```py
export_model.save("saved_model")
```

`python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model saved_model --output saved_model.onnx --extra_opset ai.onnx.contrib:1 --opset 11`

Using [onnxruntime-extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions) it is now possible to register the custom ops and to run the model in Python for inference.

```py
import onnxruntime
from onnxruntime import InferenceSession
from onnxruntime_extensions import get_library_path

so = onnxruntime.SessionOptions()
so.register_custom_ops_library(get_library_path())

session = InferenceSession('saved_model.onnx', so)
res = session.run(None, { 'text_vectorization_2_input': example_new })
```

This raises the question if it's possible to use the same model in Java in a similar way. Onnxruntime for Java does have a [SessionOptions#registerCustomOpLibrary](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/239c6ad3f021ff7cc2e6247eb074bd4208dc11e2/java/src/main/java/ai/onnxruntime/OrtSession.java#L693) function, so I thought of something like this:

```java
OrtEnvironment env = OrtEnvironment.getEnvironment();
OrtSession.SessionOptions options = new OrtSession.SessionOptions();
options.registerCustomOpLibrary(""); // reference the library
OrtSession session = env.createSession("...", options);
```

Does anyone have an idea if the use case described is feasable or how to use models with pre-processing layers in Java (without using TensorFlow Java)?

**UPDATE:**
Spotted a potential solution. If I understand the comments in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/issues/1500) correctly, one possibility is to build the [ONNXRuntime Extensions package](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions) from source (see [this explanation](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions#build-and-development)) and reference the generated library file by calling `registerCustomOpLibrary` in the ONNX Runtime Library for Java. However, as I have no experience with tools like cmake this might become a challenge for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you propose in your update is correct, you need to compile the ONNX Runtime extension package from source to get the dll/so/dylib, and then you can load that into ONNX Runtime in Java using the session options. The Python whl doesn't distribute the binary in a format that can be loaded outside of Python, so compiling from source is the only option. I wrote the ONNX Runtime Java API, so if this approach fails open an issue on Github and we'll fix it.